# How do I access a nested function in a scala object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

### I'm trying to access a nested function. I am able to access func1 but I'm running into issues when trying to access func2.

//attempting to call methods in different class

```
val t1 = test
t1.func1()
t1.func1(df).func2("test")

object test {
    def func1 (df: dataframe): tt = {

      def func2 (ab: String): String =  {
        // do something
      } else {
        // do nothing
      }

      def func3 (ab2: String): String = {
        //do something
      } else {
        // do nothing
      }

    }

  val t1 = test
  t1.func1()
  t1.func1(df).func2("test")
```

I'm expecting to access func2 without any errors

Comment: The idea of inner _methods_ is that they are **private** helpers for the outer one. They can not be accessed outside their enclosing scope _(well maybe with reflection, but I would not use that)_. Anyways... why do you want to do this? It looks like you really intended to use **curryfication**, or maybe your first _method_ should just be a constructor or a factory of an object that provide your second _method_.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider `func2` to be the equivalent of a nested variable. You aren't able to access this outside of its parent function.

Try changing a few things around to make this example more obvious:

```scala
object test {
    def func1 (df: dataframe): String = {
        val data = "hi"
        "bye"
    }
}
val t1 = test
t1.func1(df).data
```

Would you expect to be able to access `data` here?

If you try to make a reference to `func2` outside of `func1`, you will receive a compiler error.

If you need access to `func2` and don't have any other constraints, I'd recommend defining it outside the scope of `func1`.

Answer (score 3):

The closure property prevents captured identifiers to be accessed from outside the enclosed scope. Using an object or class instead of a function and overloading apply appropriately would make the inner scope accessible.

```
object test {

    case class func1(df: dataframe){

        def apply(..)= {..}

        def func2 (ab: String): String =  {..}
        def func3 (ab2: String): String = {..}
   }
}
```